How to start displaying dates from 2nd cell in LazyVerticalGrid in jetpack compose?
good morning everyone! I want to display the calendar of 2024, April in android. but first day of each month is starting from first cell of the grid. how can we start from second cell of grid?
please help me ...
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Composable
fun Calender() {
    var firstDayOfMonth = LocalDate.of(2024,4,1)

    val month= firstDayOfMonth.month
    val firstDayOfWeek = firstDayOfMonth.dayOfWeek.value

    LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(7)) {

        items(month.maxLength()) {
            if (firstDayOfMonth.dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY){
                Text(text = firstDayOfMonth.dayOfMonth.toString(), color = Color.Red)
            }else{
                Text(text = firstDayOfMonth.dayOfMonth.toString())
            }

            firstDayOfMonth= firstDayOfMonth.plusDays(1)
        }
        

    }
}

i want the series of date should start from second cell
I want to display calendar of April month of 2024.

Just add whatever item count you want to be empty. In my example 1
For dynamic solution you could pass value of firstDayOfWeek
...

LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(7)) {

        items(1) {
            Text(text = "")
        }

        items(month.maxLength()) {

...



Is it also possible to just add a single empty item {} instead of items(1) {...}? I can't test it right now.
